# Force user to make a selection on application start

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my `ASP.net` `MVC 3` (nopcommerce based) application, I need to make sure user selects his location from a list and this selection is stored in session for dynamic price calculation. Since, there could be multiple entry-points (homepage, search results, from Google indexed pages etc.) I want to make sure the location selection (may be a popup) is presented to the user as soon as he tries to view any product page that may have price. For a given session, this must be a onetime selection.

What would be the best event handler (`Application_BeginRequest`??) to perform a check if particular session variable exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could  use an action filter to check for the value in session and redirect to a view if the location is not already stored. Once captured you can redirect back to the original view.

Something like:

```
public class CheckLocationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var location = filterContext.HttpContext.Session["Location"];

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(location))
        {
            // store the requested URL for use once location has been chosen
            filterContext.Controller.TempData["ReturnToUrl"] = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url;

            // redirect to location choice view
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Location/Choose"));
        }
    }
}
```

Then use this attribute in a controller / action wherever needed:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    [CheckLocation]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // location has been checked so continue

        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an action filter to check for the session variable globally. However, if you want to show the selection UI on certain pages without redirecting, you're probably best off using a partial view with an action backing it (e.g., Html.RenderAction()).

Call the RenderAction helper within any views you want to present the user with this selection UI. The action will check for the session variable. Set some model value for the action and partial to true/false depending on whether or not the session variable exists. Then have the partial view check for that model value and show the selection UI accordingly (i.e., show the popup if the value indicates the user needs to make a selection).

Comment: This means that the location selection view would be rendered (redundantly) many times. If there is an associated database query (to retrieve the location list) this would also add overhead.

Comment: Also, action filters can be applied to view actions or controllers or globally.

Comment: The view would be given the chance to render many times, yes. However, it would check the model value to see if it actually needed to show the selection UI. Furthermore, there would be no DB hit unless the Session variable was not already present. For example, check Session var, if not present then hit DB, store in Session, return model. If the Session var is present, just set the model value and return; no DB hit.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller's action, you can check:

```
if(HttpContext.Current.Session["Shown"] == null){
    HttpContext.Current.Session["Shown"] = true;
    // turn on a flag for client to know it should show popup
}
```